# Do Akatsuki rings have abilities?

Tags: naruto

Each of Akatsuki's members wear unique rings.
I guess Itachi's one can use genjutsu.

[image]

But how about others? Can it be used as ninjutsu or genjutsu abilities?
And why does Zetsu always collect those rings after each one of the members died.

Comment: Are you sure his ring used genjutsu? Or that he used genjutsu and made it seem like his ring had powers.

Comment: not sure. according to NS- 14 (07:45) ,  he said "it possible with my finger as well" then point out with his left finger where the ring was worn.

Comment: Well, I know what he was referring to when he said that. Do you read the manga? I don't want to spoil anything.

Comment: Itachi himself can use genjutsu but his ring? I doubt it. There is something special in those rings. It's durability is extra-ordinary given the fact that they could withstand the power of it's members.

Answer (score 4):

The rings do not have abilities.

They are simply used for the Akatsuki membership, which is why Sasuke's group Taka was never really considered Akatsuki. They might have had the cloaks, but they didn't have the rings and the rings signify a true Akatsuki member.

Also, Orochimaru's ring was never replaced when he left the Akatsuki. There have been 10 Akatsuki rings total as well as 10 members of the group.

Taken from Naruto wikia

> Right thumb: "zero" (零, rei); worn by Pain. Its colour is purplish-grey.
>
> Right index finger: "blue," "green" (青, ao, shō); worn by Deidara. Its colour is teal.
>
> Right middle finger: "white" (白, bya); worn by Konan. Its colour is white.
>
> Right ring finger: "vermilion," "scarlet" (朱, shu); worn by Itachi Uchiha. Its colour is >red.
>
> Right little finger: "sign of the boar" (亥, gai); worn by Zetsu. Its colour is green.
>
> Left little finger: "sky," "void" (空, kū); worn by Orochimaru. Its colour is slate blue.
>
> Left ring finger: "south" (南, nan); worn by Kisame Hoshigaki. Its colour is yellow.
>
> Left middle finger: "north" (北, hoku); worn by Kakuzu. Its colour is dark green.
>
> Left index finger: "three" (三, san); worn by Hidan. Its colour is orange.
>
> Left thumb: "jewel," "ball," also the black king in shogi (玉, gyoku); worn by Sasori and >later by Tobi. Its colour is purple.

[image: Gedo Mazo]

Answer (score 1):

Akatsuki thinks that the rings are very valuable for some reason. You point out how Zetsu insists on collecting the rings of dead members. It's also telling that when Orochimaru actually managed to take a ring away from Akatsuki, they didn't make a new ring *and they didn't replace Orochimaru*. It's almost like the ring is more important than the person in that position.

But as of now, we don't know why Akatsuki places so much importance on the rings. They might have some kind of abilities, but if they do, we haven't seen them.

Answer (score 1):

### **Potential Spoilers!!!!**

*Read at your own risk...*

---

My theory is that the rings are what allow Pain to talk to them telepathically and for them to astral project onto the fingers of the statue. When they preform the ceremony, there are at most two-four members physically present. (often the team that captured the jinchuuriki) My guess is that the black Kanji in the rings is the same as the rods used to control the six paths of Pain telepathically, which when the members concentrate chakra into the ring they connect to Nagato. Also, it's probably time consuming to forge the rings and Nagato isn't exactly in the best of health at the point that members start dying.

I do not believe that the rings have special "powers", beyond my theory they are what help them connect to Nagato telepathically. As for Itachi's comment about other ways to cast genjutsu, you don't have to have a sharingan to cast genjutsu. Take Kurenai for instance, she's a genjutsu mistress. I don't believe Itachi relied just on his eyes and considering his failing eyesight and health, it stands to reason that he couldn't always use his eyes in excess. Likely the whole pointing the finger thing is likely a distraction for a half seal he is using on his other hand or is the half seal in and of it's self.

---

I hope this helps,

Murakmi no Kitsune

Comment: does that mean Orochimaru can still contact them through the ring?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the rings are to connect with the Gedo statue. May be their seat on the statues fingers in also where their ring should be. For example I think that Sasori's ring was in his thumb and he sat on the Gedo's thumb. Another example Orochimaru's ring was still with him and the statues had a missing spot. So Zetsu must have collected them in case of more member to make the extraction of the tailed beast quicker( if they were able to find a new member whom was willing to join) ps people are way to into Hidan being a new member and having a past