# How Genjutsu works?

Tags: naruto

As I understand Genjutsu is, affecting the opponent's chakra network with your own chakra through some medium, and create illusions in their mind. It's basically 'Yin Release' through some medium. Incase of Sharingan users, it's done through eyesight. They can cast Genjutsu when the opponent see the caster's Sharingan. That way they imply their chakra into the opponent's body.

Incase of Sage Toads and Tayuya, It's through sound. So, whoever is within the range could be affected by the Genjutsu.

The question is, Is there any other way to cast Genjutsu ? How come Kurunei is able to cast Genjutsu? Is it through eyes?

Comment: Actually it can be thru anything. Itachi cast it using his finger too, other than his eyes. For more information, ask your grandson's reincarnation, @UchihaMadara. Lol.

Comment: @SakuraiTomoki It's obvious that you can imply chakra through physical touch. But could you tell me in which episode/chapter Itachi does that?

Comment: No, no touching. Just moving his fingers and Naruto saw that, then he falls to his genjutsu. It was when Naruto, Kakashi, Sakura, adn Chiyo-baa-sama fought fake Itachi.

Comment: Sorry, I read it wrong :)

Comment: @SakuraiTomoki Actually Itachi was having a spare Sharingan in a ring in his finger. Naruto fell into genjutsu only after seeing that... So still that jutsu is cast through eye contact...

Comment: @krishna-Itachi'sfan, reference? Never heard that there is a sharingan in that ring.

Comment: @krishna-Itachi'sfan Also I doubt that Sharingan can be implanted on a non-living object like a ring.  The ring doesn't have any special abilities as per http://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/5257/do-akatsuki-rings-have-abilities . Btw, Itachi is my fav too :P

Answer (score 1):

Genjutsu was defined by Jiraiya as "an advanced form of Ninjutsu". It affects the chakra currents in the opponent's brain.

Chakra disturbances can be caused through any of the senses, sight, hearing, smell, taste or touch. Additionally, apparently, Yin type Genjutsu (genjutsu that involves creating things from nothing, like Kurenai's) can be cast on an opponent without apparent connection to the senses.

The Second Mizukage's Yin genjutsu used chakra infused steam to mess with the opponent's sense of distance, over a wide area (so lots of opponents affected at the same time).

Comment: I took this line from wikia. "According to the Second Mizukage, genjutsu fittingly falls under the broad category of Yin Release". Doesn't it mean that all Genjutsu's are some kind of Yin release ? What do you specifically mean by 'Yin Type Genjutsu' ?

Comment: The fourth databook explained that not all genjutsu is Yin, and not all Yin is genjutsu. Genjutsu that involved **creating form from nothing** are Yin genjutsu. At least, that's what I understood. The official translation for the fourth databook is not out yet.

Comment: All Yin is not Genjutsu, I agree on this. So far, we have seen sight(Sharingan),hearing(Tayuya,Toads),taste(Genjutsu pills). How do you say about Smell and Touch ? Any examples? Also, Do you agree with SakuraiTomoki's comment on Itachi casting Genjutsu by finger touch?

Comment: Itachi once casted a genjutsu on Naruto just by pointing at him.

Comment: What kind was that? Do you think it was Yin release?

Comment: The grandson shows up.

Comment: Itachi cast genjutsu on Kabuto by touching him... It is one of the ultimate dōjutsu of the Uchiha clan - **Izanami**

Comment: @krishna-Itachi'sfan Izanami is 'Yin Release'. Check [Izanami](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Izanami)